# Use selenium in odoo13

Tags: python, selenium, odoo

Anyone can use selenium or some thing similar in module odoo.

When i run selenium alone it return result normal but when i integration it in odoo module

i got error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from tab crashed
```

here is my code

```
/*helper.py*/

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from time import sleep

def get_address(tax):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    driver = Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
    driver.get("https://dichvuthongtin.dkkd.gov.vn/inf/default.aspx")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#FrontPG-2').click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_C_RptProdGroups_ctl02_LiActiveProdGroup #LnkActiveProdGroup').click()
    a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_C_UC_ENT_LIST1_ENTERPRISE_GDT_CODEFilterFld")
    a.click()
    a.send_keys(tax)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_C_UC_ENT_LIST1_BtnFilter').click()
    sleep(0.5)
    result = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_C_UC_ENT_LIST1_CtlList_ctl02_Cmd4').text
    return result
```

```
/*einvoice_invoice.py*/
from odoo import models, fields, api
from . import helper

class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = "einvoice.invoice"

    @api.onchange('tax')
    def _get_partner_info(self):
        print("haha")
        address = helper.get_address(self.tax)
        print(address)
        self.user_address= address
```

Comment: Hi I am facing same issue. Do you get any solution ?

Comment: @BalvantRamani im using selenium with phantomjs now

Answer (score 0):

the solve for this question is install Selenium Grid and PyVirtualDisplay (you can use docker for this) and try with `Remote()` option:

```
webdriver.Remote(URL_SERVER_SELENIUM, options);
```

Its works for me.